# Not able to call Odata Service in UI5

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am calling Odata service for my UI5 application. I am using below mentioned code for creating the model.

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("https://<>/sap/opu/odata/SIE/MED_TEST_OSIRIS_SRV/SalesOrderSet?$format=json");
//Getting the Data and putting in list model
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel,"table");
```

With this code , I can call the Odata and display the results in a table.

But now when I am applying filter like this :

> https://<>/sap/opu/odata/SIE/MED_TEST_OSIRIS_SRV/SalesOrderSet?$filter=Country_SP
>   eq 'DE'

I can get the results in browser's address bar but not in the code like :

```
var sUrl = "https://<>/sap/opu/odata/SIE/MED_TEST_OSIRIS_SRV/SalesOrderSet?$filter=Country_SP eq 'DE'";

var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(sUrl);
```

what I am doing wrong ? I can filter the results in the browser with the same url :(

Regards,
Mayank

Comment: what error do you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with synchronous call.

var oModelData = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

oModelData.loadData(sUrl, null, false);

Answer (score 0):

The UI5 ODataModel only supports the base address of the OData service. The model will construct filtered and sorted queries based on that base address.  It will do that for example when you supply Filters or  Sorters to an aggregation binding.

You can however use a [JSONModel](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel.html) in your case. It's agnostic to the OData query parameters and will simply call the given URL and store the results.

Comment: I am sorry , I did not understand. Could you please correct me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode URI component the filters, and then append to the base URL

```
var filter = "Country_SP eq 'DE'";
var baseUrl = "https://<>/sap/opu/odata/SIE/MED_TEST_OSIRIS_SRV/SalesOrderSet";
var sUrl = baseUrl+encodeURIComponent(filter);
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(sUrl);
```